# audio files get deleted in the storage but still show up in listview of Custom Cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, android-cursoradapter

i am creating an audio list which contains an option menu button which shows two operation rename file and delete file, i used two separate Alert-dialog for these two operations. The problem is that when i rename an audio file than it won't get deleted. Also i can only rename the file for single attempt on second attempt the dialog is not showing up. I checked in storage the file gets deleted successfully but the file is still showing up in list view.

** Cursor Adapter**

```
public class RecordsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

Context context;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public RecordsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(context,c,0);
    this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    this.context=context;
}
String AudioPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "voices/" ;
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item,parent,false);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor mCursor) {
    TextView name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_name);
    TextView details= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_details);
    ImageButton option= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option);
    final ImageButton play=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.list_play);
    final String displayName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
    final long durationMs=mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
    Date date = new Date(durationMs);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
    String dateTime=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED));
    long size=mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE));
    String sizeKb=String.valueOf(size/1024);
    name.setText(displayName);
    Log.e("data:",dateFormatted+dateTime+sizeKb);
    details.setText(dateFormatted+" on "+dateTime+" "+sizeKb+"kb");

    //start playing an audio related to item clicked on list of audios with in dialog fragment (PlayerDialog)
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String currentAudioPath=AudioPath+ displayName ;
            PlayerDialog dialog=PlayerDialog.newInstance(displayName,durationMs,currentAudioPath);
            dialog.show(fragmentManager,"Path");
        }
    });
    //start playing an audio on play button of list clicked with in dialog fragment (PlayerDialog)
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String currentAudioPath=AudioPath+ displayName ;
            PlayerDialog dialog=PlayerDialog.newInstance(displayName,durationMs,currentAudioPath);
            dialog.show(fragmentManager,"Path");
        }
    });

    //seleting delete or edit audio name by option icon on listview clicked

    option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context,v);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.action_remove_list:
                            deleteDialog(displayName);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_edit:
                            String subName=displayName.substring(0,19);
                            renameDialog(subName);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });

}


//dialog show from option menu Rename item clicked for renaming the audio name
public void renameDialog(final String currentName)
{
    Log.e("currentName:",currentName);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Rename Audio");
    final EditText input=new EditText(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(input);
    input.setText(currentName);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String pathfile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "voices/";
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            File sdCard=new File(pathfile);
            final File from=new File(sdCard,currentName+".mp3");
            final File to=new File(sdCard,input.getText().toString()+".mp3");
            from.renameTo(to);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,input.getText().toString()+".mp3");
            context.getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+ "=?",new String[]{pathfile+currentName+".mp3"});
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

//dialog show to remove the audio file selected from the list through option menu icon
public void deleteDialog(final String currentAudio){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
    alertDialog.setMessage(currentAudio);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String pathfile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "voices/";
            context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+ "=?",new String[]{pathfile+currentAudio});
                 File f=new File(pathfile+currentAudio);
                 f.delete();
          }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: post your adapter

Comment: `deleteDialog(displayName);`. How do you determine displayName? And how would it be different for a different item clicked?

Comment: `but the file is still showing up in list view.`. Well you are not removing an item from the listview upon delete. So what do you expect to happen?

Comment: you can see it in adapter these dialog's  are in courser adapter.

Comment: @pskink i added the adapter

Comment: you are not doing anything on the adapter/cursor after delete/rename.  In other adapters (ex, array) you should call `notifydatasetchanged()` with `CusrsorAdapter` there was a method `cursor.requery()` but it's deprecated now, you may want to find what to do to *refresh* the cursor and get new data in order to re-populate the listview